# How to get vendor name of debian based linux packages?

Tags: debian, package-management

rpm based Linux distribution give's vendor name like:

```
rpm -qi nano
<other info>
Vendor: CentOS
<other info>
```

How can I get vendor names for the packages in Debian based distribution?
Already tried:

```
dpkg -l
apt list
apt show <package name>
```

I need vendor name cause I am writing a script which would create CPE's of every package in my system, I was able to get package name & version but incapable of getting vendor names, If anyone knew how to get cpes from Debian based packages please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.deb` packages don’t track vendors per package; the closest equivalent is the “Origin” field of the `Release` file describing the repository from which the package can be downloaded.

To figure this out, start with `apt show`:

```
$ apt show ... | grep APT-Sources:
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
```

Then look for the corresponding `Release` file in `/var/lib/apt/lists`:

```
$ ls /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_*Release
/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_InRelease
```

Finally, look for “Origin” there:

```
$ grep Origin: /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_InRelease
Origin: Debian
```

Answer (score 1):

Debian/Ubuntu maintainers don't save this info. `apt-cache show packagename` shows information which is comparable to `rpm -qi` but there's no `Vendor` per se, only `Maintainer` which is not what you're looking for.